# Illegal mix of collations, but everything is UTF8_BIN

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii, collation

I have a YII application with a mysql db (every table & column is in UTF8_bin) but when I want to run my app on windows or osx I got this error:

General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '<='.

Note: under Ubuntu everything works fine.

Comment: If everything really used the same collation, you wouldn't see this error. You should verify e.g. by doing a `mysqldump` on the affected machine and inspect the `CREATE DATABASE` and `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Comment: how about sharing your code?

Comment: This is a db structure dump of my db, the php code is a Yii generated CRUD (so I think the php part is ok) [link](http://pastebin.com/sM10sNh8)